# SWRevealViewController and Tab Bar Controller in detail

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

This question has been asked before and has been answered, my question is not unique but there must be something missing as none of the structures I have tried works. I am simply trying to achieve the SWRevealViewController "menu" button in each of the scenes of a Tab Bar Controller.

This is the current setup:

[image]

Textwise: SWRevealViewController -> reveal view controller set controller (sw_front) -> Navigation Controller -> root view controller (segue) -> Tab Bar controller -> Navigation controller -> Scene

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if ( revealViewController )
{
    [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

This code is in the viewDidLoad method of each scene, the SWRevealViewController.h is imported and the menu button is declared.

When the menu button is pressed nothing happens.

I have been on this issue for days and I am sure it must be something simple, help really would be appreciated.

Comment: try this https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you forget sw_rear for side menu segue . those 2 screenshots can help you

sw_front and SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController for tabbar segue
[image: front]

sw_rear and SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController for sidebar viewcontroller segue

[image: rear]

and finally this is an example of tabbar with SWRevealViewController that i did look this screenshot .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code Snippet or you can use UITabBarController as root view

```
UITabBarController *tab = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller"];        
               [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:tab];
                [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

## SWRevealViewController with TabBarController in Swift 4

```
let objSideBarVC = SideBarVC(nibName: "SideBarVC", bundle: nil)
let navSidebar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objSideBarVC)
 navSidebar.navigationBar.isHidden = true
                    
let objDashboardVC = DashboardVC(nibName: "DashboardVC", bundle: nil)
let navDashboard = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objDashboardVC)
navDashboard.navigationBar.isHidden = true
                    
let mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController.init(rearViewController: navSidebar,frontViewController: navDashboard)

AppDelegate().window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
mainRevealController.pushFrontViewController(TabBarController, animated: true)
```